# Capybara assert nothing selected from dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm trying to assert that none of the options from my dropdown have been selected, but the following all fail:

```
assert page.has_select? "franchise_id", selected: nil
assert page.has_select? "franchise_id", selected: false
assert page.has_select? "franchise_id", selected: "Pick a Franchise"
```

I just want to test that my select input has nothing selected. How can I do that?

Comment: How about `assert_nil  page.find("#franchise_id").value`?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Yes, I went with `assert_equal page.find("#franchise_id"), ""` because it's not quite nil. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value of a select by calling `.value` on a `Capybara::Node::Element`.

```
assert_nil page.find("#franchise_id").value
```

or

```
# Rails specific
assert_blank page.find("#franchise_id").value
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps easier:

```
assert page.has_select? "franchise_id", selected: []
```

This works at least as of capybara 2.14.0 and perhaps earlier.